# ZMQ Pub/Sub returns ETERM

Tags: publish, zeromq, polling, subscribe

I have one ZMQ_PUB socket in one process, connected to a ZMQ_SUB socket in another process, as it's another server. The only thing I need to do is to publish as many messages I can. I'm sure it's connected first.

I'm running a load test, firing thousands of identical messages from the PUB. At the other side, I'm polling the ZMQ_SUB socket, and receiving the messages only when needed.

The weird thing is that every 1000 messages received, zmq_poll returns ETERM for about 3 times. I can't figure it out.

-- Solution in the comments bellow.

Comment: Sounds like you're running into some issue with the high water mark (HWM). By default it's set to 1000 for all sockets. To get any further than that we'll need to see some of your code. I'm not sure your setup behaves the way you want it to, by the way - when a SUB socket hits its HWM, it drops *new* incoming messages. So, what will happen when you ignore the PUB socket for a while is that when you go back to receive more messages, you will receive the *oldest* messages in your socket queue, not the *newest* messages, which have all been discarded after you hit your HWM.

Comment: thank you very much, i'll have a look at it right away.

Comment: Turns out this is happening not only wiht PUB/SUB. It happens with my req/rep too, with just few messages. zmq_poll suddenly returns -1, as if I was closing the context. Not a clue yet.

Comment: Would you re/consider your post so as to include the MCVE-code, as **StackOverflow Netiquette encourages to do?** There are many smart and knowledgeable professionals who would be happy to get the code running, however without any MCVE, there is not much to review and solve.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Turns out I was misinterpreting the return code of the poll, recv and send functions. It returns -1 everytime it gets a signal, and it does get a lot of EINTR, that's fine, perfectly normal. I can just ignore them and repeat what I was trying to do.

In my polling, I can just continue. If it came from a send or recv, I can keep trying to send or recv as long errno == EINTR.

The problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was misinterpreting the return code of the poll, recv and send functions. It returns -1 everytime it gets a signal, and it does get a lot of EINTR, that's fine, perfectly normal. I can just ignore them and repeat what I was trying to do. In my polling, I can just continue. If it came from a send or recv, I can keep trying to send or recv as long errno == EINTR. The problem is solved